# Copy boost::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<SomeData> data_ptr;
data_ptr cached_ptr;   // class member 
bool someWork(data_ptr& passed_ptr)
{
  // must copy passed_ptr = cached_ptr under some conditions
  // without pointing at the same memory 
  // I saw somewhere that I should do 
  // passed_ptr.reset(new SomeData(???))
  // I don't have a "reset" on passed_ptr
}
```

I looked at documentation;

copy and converting constructors

```
shared_ptr(shared_ptr const & r); // never throws
template<class Y> shared_ptr(shared_ptr<Y> const & r); // never throws
Requires: Y* should be convertible to T*.

Effects: If r is empty, constructs an empty shared_ptr; otherwise,
         constructs a shared_ptr that shares ownership with r.
```

I don't know how that works - is it like this ?

```
passed_ptr = shared_ptr(cached_ptr);
```

? Where would the const go ? And what does it mean that they share ownership ? Then it is not a copy, if I modify "passed_ptr", the change will affect "cached_ptr" ?

I can't find examples... Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, if you have a `shared_ptr` and you assign it to another `shared_ptr`, those two shared pointers will share ownership of the object - meaning the reference counting for the pointed object 's ownership will be increased by one.

In fact, in the above line, you do not need to construct a temporary shared pointer at all. This is enough:

```
passed_ptr = cached_ptr;
```

Anyway, copy-constructing a `shared_ptr` basically follows the same logic: you start with a shared pointer, and you end up with two shared pointers that co-own the same object (meaning that the object will be destroyed only when *both* of those shared pointers get destroyed). So when you do this:

```
passed_ptr = shared_ptr(cached_ptr);
```

You actually start with one shared pointer (`cached_ptr`) to a given object, then create a temporary one (that brings the reference count to 2) which gets in turn assigned to `passed_ptr` (bringing the reference count to 3), and eventually gets destroyed (bringing the reference count back to 2).

On the other hand, if what you want is to have `passed_ptr` as a shared pointer to a *copy* of the object being pointed to by `cached_ptr`, then you should rather do (supposing `Data` is copyable, of course):

```
passed_ptr = boost::make_shared<Data>(*cached_ptr);
```

Or, alternatively:

```
passed_ptr.reset(new Data(*cached_ptr));
```

Comment: I want an actual copy, not 2 pointers pointing at the same object. The cached_ptr's data should stay the same when I modify passed_ptr's data.

Comment: @Thalia: I expanded my answer to cover this

Comment: Thank you, I saw this before asking the question, and tried to use "reset" but it is not available.

Comment: @Thalia: That's strange, what version of boost are you using?

Comment: @Thalia: That version definitely has the `reset()` member function, see [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm). Is it possible that you are just not using it correctly? What compiler error do you get?

Comment: It didn't show in Intellisense .. Errors: error C2663: 'boost::shared_ptr<T>::reset' : 2 overloads have no legal conversion for 'this' pointer

Comment: @Thalia: My only guess is that you're calling reset on a `const std::shared_ptr<T>`. You can only call reset on a `std::shared_ptr<T>`. (T could be const though). If that's not the case, you should try to put together a very small compilable test case and post a new question with that code. You probably could get this test case to about 10 lines of code.

Comment: Thank you, I have just discovered that ! I followed the advice below, ad made my passed_ptr const. As soon as I undid that change, it worked.

Comment: Andy, one tiny question: which is better: calling reset() or boost::make_shared<Data>(cached_ptr)  ?

Comment: @Thalia: I would use `boost::make_shared<Data>(*cached_ptr)` (don't forget the `*`). Also, if you can, switch to C++11, which has `std::shared_ptr` ;)

Answer (score 9):

Okay. Let's see if we can talk about this.

```
std::shared_ptr<Data> x = std::make_shared<Data>();
std::shared_ptr<Data> y = x;

assert(x.get() == y.get());
```

If I change something about what `x` points to, that would change information about `y` as well. Because they point to the same thing.

```
x->member = 3;
assert(x->member == 3);
assert(y->member == 3);
```

I can change what `x` points to without changing what `y` points to.

```
x = std::make_shared<Data>();
assert(x.get() != y.get());
```

If I do this, then changes to `x` are not reflected to in `y`. Because they point to different things.

```
x->member = 4;
assert(x->member == 4);
assert(y->member != 4);
```

If I want to make a copy of the contents of `x`, and store that in `y`, then I need to create a new shared object.

```
y = std::make_shared<Data>(*x);
```

At this point, both `x` and `y` have that member variable set to 4. Because `x` had it set, and we created `*y` with the contents of `*x`.

```
assert(x->member == 4);
assert(y->member == 4);
```

But, because `x` and `y` are pointing to different things in memory, we can change one of them.

```
assert(x.get() != y.get();
x->member = 3;
assert(x->member == 3);
assert(y->member == 4);
```

If I was to pass a shared_ptr to a function, then it's just like the first case.

```
void func(std::shared_ptr<Data> z) {
    assert(x.get() == z.get());
}

func(x);
```

I can also release the contents of a particular shared_ptr by using `reset()`. This will cause the value that the shared_ptr is pointing at to become NULL.

```
x.reset();
assert(x.get() == NULL);
```

With regards to const correctness, it's a bit weird.

```
const std::shared_ptr<Data> x;
x.reset(); // Fails because the shared_ptr is const.
x->member = 3; // Succeeds because Data is not const.

std::shared_ptr<const Data> x;
x.reset(); // Succeeds because the shared_ptr is not const.
x->member = 3; // Fails because Data is const.
```

Comment: can I pass shared_ptr to function without it resulting in the first case?

Comment: Sure, pass it by reference.

Answer (score 1):

The usual convention would be to pass a const `shared_ptr`:

```
bool
someWork( data_ptr const& passed_ptr )
{
    //  ...
}
```

This allows using the pointer (including copying and converting
it), but not modifying it.

If you want to change what the pointer points to at the call
site, then you have to pass a non-const reference.  The simplest
policy here is, IMHO, to assign the new value to it, but you can
also call the `reset` function.

As to how it works: when you pass the pointer to a reference
parameter, you simply give the called function access to the
original pointer.  Under the hood, it's very much like
a pointer which is systematically dereferences.  And you seem to
be confusing the pointer with what it points to; it is what it
points to that is shared, not the pointer itself.  The pointer itself
behaves exactly like any other C++ object.

Comment: I didn't make it const because its contents will change - if I make it const, can I still change the data it contains ?

Comment: @Thalia: You cannot alter the state of the pointer itself (e.g. assign it), but you can alter the state of the object being pointed to

Comment: So how do I get the contents of the cached_ptr copied to the contents of the passed_ptr  - without assigning one pointer to another ?

Comment: @Thalia: You don't. In this case it is OK to accept a reference to non-`const`. Even better would be to return a shared pointer from your function (not sure what the `bool` is for, but if it is used to indicate success/failure, you may consider using exceptions instead)

Comment: @Thalia If you don't explain clearly what you are trying to do, then it's difficult to explain how to do it.  Do you want to modify the pointer, or what it points to?  Both are objects in C++, and both can be const.  In other words, you can have `shared_ptr<Data>  const&`, which is a reference to a const pointer which points to a non-const object, or you can have `shared_ptr<Data const>&`, which is a reference to a non const pointer to a const objects.  (And of course, there's `shared_ptr<Data>&`, where nothing is const, and `shared_ptr<Data const> const&`, all const.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now and will add a const to the argument.